# Entity Framework - get related entities from List<T>

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using EF4.3 with DbContext.

I have entities that I store in cookies.

When a user returns to the site, I currently parse the cookie values to List, however, the entity "BookmarkedDeals" has a navigation property of "Deal" and I would like to make the list IQueryable so I can simply attach the navigation property either eager or lazy loading

Having got a list, this is what I initially tried;

```
List<BookmarkedDeals> bd = // populate it from cookie

var query = bd.AsQueryable().Include("Deal");
```

However Deal is null.

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: You have to query your database using a fresh DbSet :     context.BookmarkedDeals.Include("Deal")

Answer (score 0):

Your "populate it from a cookie" code needs to return an `IQueryable<BookmarkedDeals>` instead of converting it to a list. That, or you need to add the call to `.Include("Deal")` directly to that code.

Doing `AsQueryable()` on a List object or any other thing that doesn't itself have a live connection to the database will never work.

**Edit:** I didn't read your question fully. If the entities themselves are stored in a cookie, it's not going to work. I would store the ID's in a cookie, and do a query that includes "Deal" based on those ID's.

Comment: Thats where I'm currently at. To be fair the BookmarkedDeals only consist of an ID and date. The reason that they are both a cookie entry and a db entity is because anonymous users get the functionality but without being tied in, members reside in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Are you eager loading the nav property before you put the list into the cookie?  If not, you should start with that.

Alternatively, you could load the nav property if you attach it to a context.

```
        var db = new YourContext();
        foreach (var deal in bd)
        db.Entry(deal).Reference(b => b.Deal).Load();
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Member 'Load' cannot be called for property 'Deal' because the entity of type 'BookmarkedDeal' does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<BookmarkedDeal>.